# Process.Start - unable to send output to log file

Tags: c#, process.start

I have the following code

```
var parameters =
    string.Format("TestSuiteDefinitions.dll /include:{0} /out:{1} /err:{2} /xml:{3}", String.Join(",", args), OutputLog, ErrorLog, ResultLog);

var p = Process.Start(GetAssemblyDirectory() + @"\NUnit\nunit-console.exe", parameters);
```

Which allows me from my application to launch a separate process launching the NUnit console with my required outputs. The problem is the actual NUnit output is the only thing written to the logs. If the process fails for some other reason, the command output you would have seen from nunit-console.exe at a command prompt level is lost.

I have tried adding

```
> CommandOutput.txt
```

or

```
| CommandOutput.txt
```

at the end of the Process.Start parameter string but it throws an error then so doesn't like that.

Could anyone suggest how to do this? And I cant use the standardoutput stream of Process as the calling process needs to shut down as soon as the other Process is launched so cannot stay open reading and writing a stream.

Comment: What is the value of p when it fails or completes.

Answer (score 3):

`Process.Start` doesn't start a shell, but rather just spawns a process. So it's not a surprise that redirections and pipes won't work. You can pass a [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) instance to `Process.Start` where you can set `RedirectStandardOutput` and write it to a file yourself from `p.StandardOutput`.

Comment: The only issue there is that my calling project will need to stay open until the other process quits and finishes. I need the calling project to shut down once it has spawned the new process, and for the new process to be responsible for directing its standard output somewhere. Is that possible?

Comment: If the process can't write file output by itself, then you'll always need another process to read its output and write it to a file. Whether that's your own or `cmd` is another matter.